# Can't have Boost::mutex as private class member when using with std::deque?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, deque

I'm having some trouble with deque and boost::mutex, I've made a simple example that will compile with the error below.

The problem is that I want to have a deque of some class which has one or more mutexes as a private member. Though currently the example gives an error:

error C2248: 'boost::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::mutex'

I have seen some related posts but so far I have not managed to solve this specific problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>  
#include <deque>  

using namespace std;

class object {
public:
    void process(void)
    {
        m_mutex.lock();
        // do something
        a = a*10;
        m_mutex.unlock();
    }
    object(int v){  a = v; }        
private:
    int a;
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{
    deque<object> obj; 

    obj.push_back( object( 1 ) );
    obj.push_back( object( 2 ) );
    obj.push_back( object( 3 ) );

    obj.at(0).process();
    obj.at(1).process();
    obj.at(2).process();

    return 0;  
};
```

Comment: You should use a scoped lock type instead of calling lock/unlock manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to bother writing copy constructors to avoid copying the mutex, you could instead use a [Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/) from Boost.

For example:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_deque.hpp>
...
boost::ptr_deque<object> obj;
obj.push_back(new object());
obj[0].process()
...
```

Now the deque behaves just like a normal deque but it never tries to copy any `object` instances.

Answer (score 4):

```
obj.push_back( object( 1 ) );
```

The above line creates a temporary `object` instance which is then copy constructed into the deque element. Since `boost::mutex` is not copy constructible, the compiler cannot synthesize a copy constructor for `object`.

If that's the only place where you need `object` to be copy constructible change the statement to

```
obj.emplace_back( 1 );
```

`emplace_back` causes the `object` instance to be constructed in place, instead of using copy construction.

---

If you don't have access to C++11 features, change the `object` class to the following:

```
#include <memory>

class object {
public:
    void process(void)
    {
        m_mutex->lock();
        // do something
        a = a*10;
        m_mutex->unlock();
    }
    object(int v)
    : m_mutex( std::make_shared<boost::mutex>() )
    {  
      a = v; 
    }     

private:
    int a;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::mutex> m_mutex;
};
```

In VS2008 you may have to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The mutex is not CopyConstructible, so your type's copy constructor is ill-formed.

You could provide a user-defined copy constructor which doesn't copy the mutex.

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned that I already realize this from the posts I read, but how could it be solved?

Comment: what would the custom copy constructor look like? I don't understand.

Comment: By omitting the mutex copy in a custom copy constructor, you're possibly avoiding one problem and creating another one. What if one thread has acquired a lock, and another does something to the `deque` that requires the object to be copied?

Comment: object(const object& o) : a(o.a) {}

Comment: Yes, it's not without problems, but can be used if careful.

Comment: Adding this line to the class works, but I have to admit I don't really understand why or how, but I guess that is my problem. I think Inverse's solution is the most elegant.

Comment: If you don't understand how a copy constructor works are you sure you should be using mutexes for multithreaded programs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy mutexs and as such you also can't copy your class containing the mutex. As an alternative you can make a deque of `unique_ptr`s to your class

```
 std::deque<std::unique_ptr<object>> obj;
```

Comment: This looks nice, but it appears it's not an option under VS2008, only in the newer STL using the #include<memory>   -- Does this sound right?

Comment: @AlexS you could use a boost::shared_ptr as a stop gap solution. Or, since your use of the objects seems quite localized, raw pointers could be an option.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks but if using boost it seems Inverse's solution is the most straightforward.